# How to execute a query with a `has many` association using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backbone.js

I have a setup with Node, Express, and using backbone.  Everything works fine and I'm able to retrieve records from by MongoDB collections when they are simple as in getting employees by id or all employees.  What I'm having trouble understanding is how to get collections from MongoDB that require a more complex query syntax like the following:

```
db.employees.aggregate(
   [
     { $group : { _id : "$managerName", employees: { $push: "$fullName" } } }
   ]
)
```

I currently have the following syntax for extracting the data I want to expose as a json object and bind to the elements in my html page.

```
exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    var id = parseInt(req.params.id);
    db.collection('employees', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({'id': id}, function(err, item) {
            res.jsonp(item);
        });
    });
};
```

I want to get a list of all Managers and they employees that report to them and then somehow bind this result set to individual divs that would list a Manager as the List heading, and then all the employees that report to them as list items.  The result set will essentially consist of parents and childs.  I want to do this dynamically using backbonejs.

Would I be doing something like

```
exports.findRelations = function(req, res) {
    db.collection('employees', function(err, collection) {
        collection.aggregate({ $group : { _id : "$managerName", employees:{$push: "$fullName" } } }, function(err, item) {
            res.jsonp(item);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation pipeline for MongoDB requires that you pass the operations in an Array. This means the correct query would be:

```
db.collection('employees').aggregate([
    { $group : { _id : "$managerName", employees:{$push: "$fullName" } }
  ])
  .toArray(function(err, managers){
    if (err){
      throw err;
    }

    res.jsonp(managers);
  });
```

You'll find details for using the aggregation pipeline with the NodeJS MongoDB driver here: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/aggregation/

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work, but there is something odd.  When I run my MongoDB script in robomongo I get the right resultset which is a list of employees by manager. So all managers are listed and then then nested are all the employees that report to them.  But when I use the same exact syntax in my code as above the resultset I get is simply all the records in my collection as though my MongoDB script is being ignored.  Why would that be?

Comment: I think I understand your question now. The syntax for the MongoDB client (through RoboMongo) and the Node.js driver for MongoDB are different. While the client requires a query in this form: `db.employees`, the Node.js driver requires a query in this form: `db.collection('employees')`

Comment: Actually I figured out how to make it work, but I don't understand why.  I need to research it a bit more.  But I figured it out based on the link you shared above.  I basically had to add square brackets around my query in node.js so the final syntax was:  collection.aggregate([{ $group : { _id : "$managerName", employees:{$push: "$fullName" }}}]) So Gnerkus your response about passing an array was correct and worked.

Comment: Sorry but how do you do formatting when doing add comment?  Not sure if this is the place to ask this.

Comment: It isn't but I'll answer anyway: you can use regular markdown. For example, surround expressions in backticks (``) to format them to look like `code`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108059/discussion-between-gnerkus-and-user1991118).